# Excel sheet is not opening in Mozilla

Tags: jsp

I have a download link on JSP to download an excel file. I have written a simple href as below:
a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/templates/XLS_Temp_late.xls" target="_blank"> Link 
I am able to download the excel file both in IE9 and in Mozilla when I am testing in local.
But when the same code is deployed to server, the download link works fine in IE9 but in Mozilla it isopening in a new browser window with special characters. Actually the open/ save popup is not coming .

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Hi Tom,
I didnot get what I need to do. Sorry about that. Could you please explain more what ar you suggesting for me to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to a resource package with a label, on the line
 the  download 
 The principle extension as long as the web server can not resolve, usually to save it to a local form of the http

Answer (score 0):

I asked asked my colleagues on this issue, he said that this situation is likely to be because IE and mozilla different kernel code so you can work in IE but mozilla does not support this way, you shouldproblems screenshots hair look better, because of the same problem may be ten thousand kinds of causes can not be generalized, I hope you can help.Sorry my English is not very good, Nengkanmingbai your question, but not good English expression, so I used google translate, I hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

I asked asked my colleagues on this issue, he said that this situation is likely to be because IE and mozilla different kernel code so you can work in IE but mozilla does not support this way, you shouldproblems screenshots hair look better, because of the same problem may be ten thousand kinds of causes can not be generalized, I hope my answers help you.My English is not very good, I can understand your question, but can not be expressed well in English, so I used google translator, I hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

I asked my colleagues on this issue, he said that this is likely to be because IE and mozilla using a different kernel, so your code in IE normal work, but mozilla does not support this way, you should Screenshothair look better, the same problem may be ten thousand kinds of causes can not be generalized, I hope my answers help you.My English is not very good, I can understand your question, but can not be expressed well in English, so I used google translator, I hope you can understand